# GTK3 - scale with range in builder.ui

Tags: gtk

I'm trying to add a GTK Scale with range object to a builder.ui file. Originally I had this:-

```
GtkWidget *distance;
distance = gtk_scale_new_with_range (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0, 6, 0.5);
gtk_scale_set_draw_value (GTK_SCALE (distance), TRUE);
gtk_scale_set_value_pos(GTK_SCALE (distance), GTK_POS_RIGHT);
```

This works fine, but how can I add the same thing to a builder.ui file instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. `gtk_scale_new_with_range()` is a convenience function for creating a `GtkScale` with some properties already set, so you'll have to look at its [source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkscale.c?id=dfe1c63c9b92ae64bdd0cac7bf57261363c4ec17#n603) in order to replicate it. So your UI file should look something like this (untested):

```
<object class="GtkScale" id="distance">
  <property name="orientation">horizontal</property>
  <property name="draw-value">TRUE</property>
  <property name="value-pos">right</property>
  <property name="adjustment">distance-adjustment</property>
  <property name="digits">1</property>
</object>
<object class="GtkAdjustment" id="distance-adjustment">
  <property name="value">0</property>
  <property name="lower">0</property>
  <property name="upper">6</property>
  <property name="step-increment">0.5</property>
  <property name="page-increment">5</property>
  <property name="page-size">0</property>
</object>
```